# Can't pass a toBeInstanceOf test

Tags: jestjs, nestjs

I am working on a TTD project, using NestJs and Jest. Everything was fine until now, I can't figure how to pass my toBeInstanceOf test. The object returned should be of type User, but jest tells me :

```
expect(received).toBeInstanceOf(expected)

Expected constructor: User
Received constructor: Object
```

Here is the test :

```
import { IRepository } from '../../../core/src/domain/repositories/IRepository.interface';
import { User } from '../../src/domain/entities/user.entity';
import { CreateUserUseCase } from '../../src/useCases/createUser.usecase';

const fakeUser: User = {
  id: 1,
  uuid: 'some-uuid',
  createdAt: new Date(),
  updatedAt: new Date(),
  email: '',
  password: '',
};

const userToCreate = new User();
userToCreate.email = 'test@gmail.com';
userToCreate.password = 'test';

describe('CreateUserUseCase', () => {
  let useCase: CreateUserUseCase;
  let repository: IRepository<User>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    repository = {
      insert: jest.fn((entity: User) => {
        const newUser: User = {
          ...fakeUser,
          email: entity.email,
          password: entity.password,
        };

        return Promise.resolve(newUser);
      }),
    } as IRepository<User>;

    useCase = new CreateUserUseCase(repository);
  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(useCase).toBeDefined();
  });

  describe('execute', () => {
    it('should creates a new user', async () => {
      const createdUser: User = await useCase.execute(userToCreate);

      expect(createdUser).toBeInstanceOf(User);
      expect(createdUser).toEqual({
        ...fakeUser,
        email: userToCreate.email,
        password: userToCreate.password,
      });

      expect(repository.insert).toBeCalledTimes(1);
      expect(repository.insert).toBeCalledWith({
        email: userToCreate.email,
        password: userToCreate.password,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

** createUser.usecase.ts **

```
import { IRepository } from '../../../core/src/domain/repositories/IRepository.interface';
import { User } from '../domain/entities/user.entity';

export class CreateUserUseCase {
  constructor(private readonly _repository: IRepository<User>) {}

  async execute(userToCreate: User): Promise<User> {
    const createdUser: User = await this._repository.insert(userToCreate);
    return createdUser;
  }
}
```

** IRepository **

```
import { BaseEntity } from '../entities/base.entity';

export interface IRepository<T extends BaseEntity> {
  insert(entity: T): Promise<T>;
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your `insert` mock returns an object that *looks* like a `User` but isn't an instance of the class itself, so `toBeInstanceOf()` fails. It's like having something like this:

```js
class Foo {
  foo: string
}

expect({  foo: 'Hello World!' }).toBeInstanceOf(Foo);
```

You'd expect this to fail, even though the object satisfies the structure of `Foo`, because it's a regular object, not an actual instance.

Change your `insert` mock to return an instance of the class and your test should resolve itself.